# Getting "subquery returned multiple results" error while retrieving specific rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to get specified rows from a temp table. Below is my code:

```
Select 
        t.pub_id, m.KEY_DATE_VALUE
INTO
        #temp1
FROM 
        #temp t
        JOIN CUSTOM_META m
ON 
        t.pub_id = m.ITEM_ID
        AND m.KEY_NAME = 'ArticleDate'
ORDER BY 
        m.KEY_DATE_VALUE DESC 

Select * from #temp1
```

Displays:

```
154477  2014-03-03 20:56:00.000
155001  2014-03-03 18:00:00.000
155000  2014-03-03 17:57:00.000
154999  2014-03-03 17:55:00.000
154998  2014-03-03 17:52:00.000
154463  2014-03-03 16:45:10.000
154461  2014-03-03 16:41:11.000
```

But on doing:

```
Select pub_id from( select pub_id, Row_Number() over (order by pub_id) as 
item_number from #temp1) AS mYtABLE WHERE mYtABLE.item_number BETWEEN 1 AND 5
```

The order of items change.

How can I modify the second statement so that the order remains as it is.

Comment: The subquery in your `SELECT` statement is returning multiple values. From what I can see, there can be upto 9 values (read rows) returned by the subquery, when it is allowed to select only one or none.

Comment: Perhaps you can replace `BETWEEN 1 AND 9` by `= 1`? Or just use `(SELECT DISTINCT pub_id FROM #temp) AS pub_id`?

Comment: But I want all rows from 1 to 9.

Comment: Then take your subquery out and do a left join or cross join .

Comment: Can you share schema & sample date for Fast ans.

Comment: I tried something more. Please see the updated question now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select pub_id,KEY_DATE_VALUE DESC
INTO
        #temp1
FROM 
        (
        select pub_id, Row_Number() over (order by pub_id desc) as 
        item_number from #temp) AS mYtABLE WHERE mYtABLE.item_number BETWEEN 1 AND 9
    ) t
        JOIN CUSTOM_META m
ON 
        t.pub_id = m.ITEM_ID
        AND m.KEY_NAME = 'ArticleDate'
ORDER BY 
        m.KEY_DATE_VALUE DESC
```

Order the resultset by KEY_DATE_VALUE DESC as below

```
select pub_id from #temp1
order by KEY_DATE_VALUE DESC
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But the results are not sorted anymore on date. :(

Comment: Ordering is not guaranteed until you use it in a SELECT statement

Comment: Then please suggest a way out by using it in select itself. Ordering is the whole reason this stored procedure is being written.

Comment: Include KEY_DATE_VALUE in the #temp1 table. Check if my modified code works correctly

Comment: I want to sort the results first and then select specific rows. This will do reverse.